# Thread is not acquiring monitor after notify calls

Tags: java, multithreading

I just made one producer and one consumer thread. When list is empty consumer went to waiting state, then producer insert an item in list and calls `notify()` to invoke consumer thread but consumer is not invoking. It remains in waiting state.

Code that I have tried is:

```
package xs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        product pro = new product();
        producer produce = new producer(pro);
        consumer consume = new consumer(pro);
        Thread thr1 = new Thread(produce, "Producer");
        Thread thr2 = new Thread(consume, "consumer");
        thr1.start();
        thr2.start();
    }
}

class product{
    List<Date> list;
    public product() {
        list = new ArrayList<Date>();
    }

    public void produce(Date i){
        list.add(i);
    }

    public Date consume(){
        return list.remove(0);
    }
}

class producer implements Runnable{
    product product;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            synchronized (this) {
                while(product.list.size() == 2){
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                product.produce(new Date());
                System.out.println("Produced "+product.list.size());
                notify();
            }
        }
    }


    public producer(product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

}

class consumer implements Runnable{
    product product;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(true){
            synchronized (this) {
                notify();
                while(product.list.size() == 0){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Going to wait..."+ product.list.size());
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("consumed"+ product.consume());
            }
        }
    }

    public consumer(product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

Output it's giving:

```
Going to wait...0
Produced 1
Produced 2
```

As you can see consumer is not coming in action after `wait()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your producer and consumer are each synchronizing, waiting and notifying *their own monitor*. You need to give them a *shared* monitor to use for synchronization etc.

For example:

```
Object monitor = new Object();
product pro = new product();
producer produce = new producer(monitor, pro);
consumer consume = new consumer(monitor, pro);
```

Change both the `producer` and `consumer` constructors to accept another parameter (of type `Object`) and save it in a field, then change `synchronized(this)` to `synchronized(monitor)`, `wait()` to `monitor.wait()` and `notify()` to `monitor.notify()` and all will be well.

(You *could* just use `product` to synchronize on, but personally I prefer to use an object which is *only* used for synchronization, or an object of a thread-centric class designed specifically for this.)

Also, note that your code feels very un-Java-like due to your class names, which should be `Product`, `Producer` and `Consumer` to follow normal Java naming conventions.

Comment: You mean IPC exists only within same monitor?

Comment: @DeepakTiwari: There's no IPC here - you've only got a single process! But yes, each monitor is separate in terms of synchronization, waiting and notifying. It would be very hard to write scalable code otherwise, if there was logically just a single monitor for the whole system.

Comment: I am adopting your method but due to that I am getting illegalmonitorstateException.

Comment: You can see the edited question. It has changed that you have suggested.

Comment: @DeepakTiwari: Now you've made my answer look incorrect, because your code no longer has the original problem - please don't do that. (It would be better to rollback your edit.) But the problem is that you've only implemented *some* of my suggestions - you're still calling `wait()` instead of `monitor.wait()`, and ditto for `notify()`.

Comment: Sorry for the blunder.

Answer (score -2):

@deepak : you have made one mistake you passed string name lower case
Thread thr2 = new Thread(consume, "consumer");

in place on you should pass 
 Thread thr2 = new Thread(consume, "Consumer");

in which "Consumer" is class name of consumer

I got this output:

```
Produced 1
Produced 2
consumedTue Oct 07 13:29:44 IST 2014
consumedTue Oct 07 13:29:44 IST 2014
Going to wait...0
```

Comment: It's just the thread name. It has no relation with class name.